# How to get part of URL and print it in "src" attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My URL = http://jafkz.com/index.php#23

My Code:  (read JS comments, how to make step 2 and 3 ?)

```
 <script>

function mdlbox() {
     //step 1: Show modal box
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName('modalDialog');
        y[0].style.display = 'block';

    //step 2: Get hash value from My URL

    //step 3: Add this value to src attribute in My Div 
    }
    </script>
```

my Div:

```
<div id="videobox">
                    <video>

                    <source src="videos/" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
 </div>
```

How to make `src` looks like this `src="videos/23"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.querySelector('#videobox > video > source').src` to set its url

```js
function mdlbox() {
     //step 1: Show modal box
  //var y = document.getElementsByClassName('modalDialog');
        //y[0].style.display = 'block';

    //step 2: Get hash value from My URL

    //step 3: Add this value to src attribute in My Div 
    document.querySelector('#videobox > video > source').src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4";//change it as "videos/23" in your case
    }
    mdlbox();
```

```html
<div id="videobox">
                    <video controls autoplay>

                    <source src="videos/" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
 </div>
```

Comment: Yes working ty but, first loading the html structure then script and video is not playing .. How to refresh div as well ?

Comment: You dont need to refresh the div. just add `controls autoplay` in the `video` tag as like the updated answer ^

Comment: `controls autoplay`  are added already... I am cheking from **inspect element** and i see the **src** is correct link is correct, but video is not playing.. I think this is becouse loading queue of codes maybe..

Comment: might be your net issue. it works fine here. I even tried it in different browser. the video is playing well

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the value behind the # in your current url. (In your case '23') You can do something like this:

```
//step 2: Get` hash value from My URL
var hasValue = window.location.hash.substr(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

step 2: Get hash value from My URL

var myHash =  window.location.hash.substr(1);

step 3: Add this value to src attribute in My Div

document.querySelector('#videobox > video > source').src = 'videos/'+myHash;

step 4: Reload and play video

document.querySelector('#videobox > video').load();

document.querySelector('#videobox > video').play();

Comment: The link is dynamic, can be #23 or #24 or #27 or something else,,, Just **My URL** is not a variable, ty

Comment: `var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);` should be like this maybe

Comment: Yeah - that would probably work. As long as your location is where the URL is coming from.

Comment: TY guys the another problem is after add to **src** attribute the video is not playing , how to refresh video player

Comment: I've been updating my original post as you've been commenting. A quick search can tell you how to use the video object: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp